# Подскажите, как прервать скролл главной страницы в то время когда скролишь слайдер колесиком мышки

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, прокрутка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня на странице есть слайдер с карточками, и когда мышкой наводишь на область что бы про скролить карточки колесиком мышки то главная страница в этот момент тоже скролиться. Подскажите пожалуйста  как прервать это событие? спасибо.
Код написан реакт + TS стилизация chakra

```
export const AdvisersCards = memo(() => {
  const { data } = useGetAdvisersCardsQuery(null);

  const [isDown, setIsDown] = useState(false);
  const [startX, setStartX] = useState(0);
  const [scrollLeftState, setScrollLeftState] = useState<null | number>(null);
  const [mouseMoved, setStateMouseMoved] = useState(0);

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(4);
  const [updateMockdata, setUpdateMockData] = useState(mockAdvisersCards.slice(0, 4));

  const listContainer = useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null);

  function handleMouseDown(e: React.MouseEvent) {
    setIsDown(true);

    if (listContainer.current !== null) {
      setStartX(e.pageX - listContainer.current.offsetLeft);
      setScrollLeftState(listContainer.current.scrollLeft);
    }

    setStateMouseMoved(0);
  }

  function handleMouseMove(e: React.MouseEvent) {
    if (!isDown) {
      return;
    }
    let currentMousePositionInsideContainer;
    if (listContainer.current !== null) {
      currentMousePositionInsideContainer = e.pageX - listContainer.current.offsetLeft;
    }
    if (currentMousePositionInsideContainer !== undefined) {
      setStateMouseMoved(currentMousePositionInsideContainer - startX);
    }
  }
Вот здесть событие на скролл
>   function handleWheele(e: React.WheelEvent) {
>     if (listContainer.current !== null) {
>       listContainer.current.scrollLeft += e.deltaY;
>     }   
> }[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

  const handleShowMore = useCallback(() => {
    if (mockAdvisersCards.length <= 4) {
      return;
    }
    setCounter(counter + 3);
    setUpdateMockData(mockAdvisersCards.slice(0, counter + 3));
  }, [counter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (listContainer.current !== null && scrollLeftState !== null) {
      listContainer.current.scrollLeft = scrollLeftState - mouseMoved;
    }
  }, [scrollLeftState, mouseMoved]);

  return (
    <Box w='1334px' m='0 auto'>
      <Heading fontSize='60px' textAlign='center' mb='60px'>
        Найди своего ментора
      </Heading>
      <List
        overflow={'hidden'}
        ref={listContainer}
        display='flex'
        alignItems='center'
        justifyContent='space-between'
        flexDirection='row'
        gap='20px'
        userSelect='none'
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={() => setIsDown(false)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsDown(false)}
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
        onWheel={handleWheele}
      >
        {updateMockdata &&
          updateMockdata.map((item) => {
            return (
              <AdviserCard
                key={item.id}
                name={item.name}
                skills={item.skills}
                position={item.position}
              />
            );
          })}
        {updateMockdata.length !== mockAdvisersCards.length && (
          <Box ml='137px' display='flex' flexDirection='column'>
            <Button onClick={handleShowMore} w='150px' h='150px' borderRadius='50%' mb='20px'>
              <HandIcon width={'50px'} height={'50px'} viewBox=''>
                <HandMotion>
                  <HandSeeMoreSvg width={52} height={52} />
                </HandMotion>
              </HandIcon>
            </Button>
            <Text fontSize='24px' lineHeight='1.1' color='text.sub' opacity='.5'>
              показать еще
            </Text>
          </Box>
        )}
      </List>
    </Box>
  );
});

Картинка то как выглядит слайдер на странице
```

Comment: Попробуйте задать CSS свойство, контейнеру слайдера `overscroll-behavior: contain;` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior)

Comment: Благодарю, помогло. Контейнеру пришлось изменить свойство overflow: 'hidden', на overflowX: 'scroll'